# Scroll two columns but only one get stucked after the text is finished

Tags: javascript, html, css

So basically, I would like to scroll images and text at the same time, but when the bottom of the text shows up, I would like it to stop, while I could keep scrolling images.

I tried to use sticky position on the text, but it scrolls only when I scroll all the images. I maybe used it the wrong way.

In this example, I’ve replaced images by color boxes.

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}
nav{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #ffc3d9;
  height: 50px;
}
section, aside{
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 50vw;
  
}
.block{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
p{
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>

</nav>
<section>
  <div class="block" style="background:#ffff61;">
    
  </div>
  <div class="block" style="background:#61fff1;">
    
  </div>
  <div class="block" style="background:#f561ff;">
    
  </div>
</section>
<aside>
  <p>Cat ipsum dolor sit amet, really likes hummus but put butt in owner's face spend all night ensuring people don't sleep sleep all day proudly present butt to human. Behind the couch pooping rainbow while flying in a toasted bread costume in space poop in a handbag look delicious and drink the soapy mopping up water then puke giant foamy fur-balls for carefully drink from water glass and then spill it everywhere and proceed to lick the puddle meow. Disappear for four days and return home with an expensive injury; bite the vet i like frogs and 0 gravity why can't i catch that stupid red dot leave buried treasure in the sandbox for the toddlers so with tail in the air or catch mouse and gave it as a present.</p>
</aside>
```

Is it possible ? If yes, how ?

**EDIT:**
I tried again using sticky position, but no matter what I use (top or bottom, with a full height column or not) it doesn't work. Is there an another solution ? Maybe some JS ?

Comment: Can you try fixed position ??

Comment: I can't scroll if I put fixed on aside ([link](https://jsfiddle.net/0f5qLh8j/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used JS

```
if(window.innerWidth > 600){
  var element = document.getElementById("scroll-text");
  let toScroll = element.scrollHeight + element.offsetTop;
  if(toScroll > window.innerHeight){
      toScroll += 60;
      window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
          let windowScroll = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight;
          if(windowScroll > toScroll){
              if(!element.classList.contains("fixed")){
                  element.classList.toggle("fixed");
              }
          }else{
              if(element.classList.contains("fixed")){
                  element.classList.toggle("fixed");
              }
          }
      });
  }else{
      element.classList.toggle("fixedtop");
  }
}
```

.fixed is fixed bottom 0,
.fixedtop is fixed top. It works quite well. It's probably not the best way to do it but w/e it works ahah.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: sticky;` and set a top value:

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}
nav{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #ffc3d9;
  height: 50px;
}
section, aside{
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 50vw;
  
}
.block{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
p{
  margin: 10px;
  position: sticky;
  top:50px;
}
```

```html
<nav>

</nav>
<section>
  <div class="block" style="background:#ffff61;">
    
  </div>
  <div class="block" style="background:#61fff1;">
    
  </div>
  <div class="block" style="background:#f561ff;">
    
  </div>
</section>
<aside>
  <p>Cat ipsum dolor sit amet, really likes hummus but put butt in owner's face spend all night ensuring people don't sleep sleep all day proudly present butt to human. Behind the couch pooping rainbow while flying in a toasted bread costume in space poop in a handbag look delicious and drink the soapy mopping up water then puke giant foamy fur-balls for carefully drink from water glass and then spill it everywhere and proceed to lick the puddle meow. Disappear for four days and return home with an expensive injury; bite the vet i like frogs and 0 gravity why can't i catch that stupid red dot leave buried treasure in the sandbox for the toddlers so with tail in the air or catch mouse and gave it as a present.</p>
</aside>
```

Comment: It's not fluid, it stops in the middle as [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nveyj9q2/3/) (I put 0 to top because it waits to be scrolled by 50px before start scrolling with your code)